# PlotMarkers not differently colored when Joined->True, InterpolationOrder and Mesh->True in ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, data, dataset

I have some data I need to plot smoothly. I am using ListPlot and Joined; to make them smooth, I found I need to use InterpolationOrder->3; then, to have only markers on the data set, I am using Mesh->Full, but I get some weird behavior. Colors of markers are only blue and a part of the third curve vanishes.
How do I get markers with colors of the curve, different for each curve?

```
Z00 = {{0.`, 410.07215877001596`}, {0.1`, 410.346099148169`}, {0.25`, 
412.554711875091`}, {0.3`, 414.003252267871`}, {0.4`, 
419.207372319724`}, {0.49`, 435.436031631739`}};

Z006 = {{0.`, 407.90130077490403`}, {0.1`, 
408.17433459836303`}, {0.25`, 410.370028165589`}, {0.3`, 
411.81120194816503`}, {0.4`, 416.99501296245097`}, {0.49`, 
433.178028406407`}};

Z002 = {{0.`, 385.219627658663`}, {0.1`, 385.47437566168`}, {0.25`, 
387.49055954758103`}, {0.3`, 388.83276041643103`}, {0.4`, 
393.75318408081097`}, {0.49`, 409.415785093289`}};

ListPlot[{Z00, Z006, Z002}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, 
Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
PlotRange -> All, 
GridLines -> All, ImageSize -> {1000, 600}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"poisson", "Eigenfrequency [kHz]"}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 14]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
in1 = Interpolation[Z00, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
in2 = Interpolation[Z006, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
in3 = Interpolation[Z002, InterpolationOrder -> 3];

Show[{
  ListPlot[{Z00, Z006, Z002}, Mesh -> Full, PlotRange -> All, 
   GridLines -> All, ImageSize -> {1000, 600}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"poisson", "Eigenfrequency [kHz]"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 14]],

  Plot[{in1[x], in2[x], in3[x]}, {x, 0, 0.5}]
  }]
```

yielding this

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: good trick! Thanks

Comment: On V11.2 (MacOS), all the mesh points are the same color. I thought they were the plot markers, but after looking further, I found I needed to omit `Mesh -> Full` in the `ListPlot`. (Your image also does not have the standard V11 colors, which makes me think you're using a different version or options.)

Comment: @ Michael E2 I use Win7. Yes, I also noticed something strange. Namely, if I took the ImageSize used by the author, I obtained what you see in my answer, but as soon as I decreased the size (just to comfortably publish the image) all the dots strangely became blue, while the lines appeared as in the image. I did not dig into it. After all the OP wanted this size.

Comment: I see. I get that, too. I automatically delete `ImageSize` from code -- I find it annoying. I didn't realize its significance.  I assume on size is absolute and one size is relative.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way, without the need to combine multiple plots of the same data with `Show`, is to use `PlotMarkers` option instead of `Mesh->Full`. If you use `PlotMarkers->Automatic`, as [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8867398/673852) does, you'll get the default sequence of markers like circles, squares etc. To get simply colored points, you can do like here:

```
ListPlot[Transpose@Table[{Sin[n], Cos[n]}, {n, 1, 10}],
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Graphics@{Point[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image: output of the above command]

You can use all the normal elements of `Graphics` sequence, e.g. to make points larger you'd use

```
ListPlot[Transpose@Table[{Sin[n], Cos[n]}, {n, 1, 10}], 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Graphics@{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image: output of the above command]

Comment: PlotMarkers -> Automatic is also possible

Comment: @partida I did mention this option in this answer, please read the first paragraph on how it doesn't (quite) work.

Comment: Oh, Excuse me I read carelessly.